# Quantum field theory prerequisites

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, education

I am starting to learn Quantum field theory. What are the prerequisites from quantum mechanics? Please tell me the topics of quantum mechanics that are needed.

Comment: Are you starting to study QFT without having previously studied QM?

Comment: @Ghoster Yessssssss

Comment: Self-study or university course?

Comment: @Ghoster Self-study

Comment: You need to master regular non-relativistic QM before trying to learn QFT. Trying to leap straight into QFT will be an exercise in frustration.

Comment: @JohnRennie I mean qm is huge. Could you tell me what are necessary(bare minimum) topics in qm to be covered before going to qft

Comment: If you think QM is huge you have an unpleasant surprise waiting for you when you start trying to learn QFT. It's **much** harder.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably be comfortable with quantum mechanics before moving on to QFT, because the latter is, as was pointed out in the comments, much harder.

Here is a (very) non-exhaustive list of topics you should be familiar with before learning QFT :

- the axioms of quantum mechanics : states, observables, transition amplitudes, the Schrödinger equation, canonical commutation relations, stationary states
- the Schrödinger, Heisenberg and interaction pictures, the time evolution operator
- the harmonic oscillator : its Hamiltonian and its solution in terms of ladder operators
- symmetries : unitary operators, hermitian generators of continuous symmetries, Noether's theorem
- spin : finite dimension unitary representation of the rotation group, half integer spin
- perturbation theory : both time dependent and time independent, Fermi's golden rule

Comment: Scattering theory ?